# list passed with default parameter is considered as a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I tried to call this function (only the first line matters):

```
def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return None
```

like this:

```
find_path(self.neighbors, (4,4), (0,4))
```

but I always get this error:

```
    path = path + [start]
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

I know that I cannot change a tuple, but I assumed `path` is a list, and when I check it's type it says tuple, how come? what's your suggestion to solve it? thanks

Comment: Is `find_path` a function or a method? You're calling it with `self.neighbors` as the first argument, so are you missing a `def find_path(self, ...)`?

Comment: also be VERY CAREFUL about using mutable default arguments. This should work in this case, but it's one of those "gotchas" that are easy to screw up (for example if your first line was `path.append(start)`!

Comment: Thanks @AdamSmith , that was really the problem, I feel awkward that I didn't notice that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, the context of this code looks like:

```
class SomeClass:

    ...
    def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        ...
```

In which case when you call it, it passes

```
find_path(graph=self, start=self.neighbors, end=(4,4), path=(0,4))
```

You need to define that method with the signature

```
def find_path(self, graph, start, end, path=[])
```

A note on mutable default arguments: be **very careful** when you decide to use them. It works in this case because the first thing you do is redefine `path` inside the scope of the method with `path = path + [start]`, but if your first line was the otherwise-identical `path.append(start)`, your method would be *very* hard to debug.

Default arguments are scoped at the same level as the function they belong to, so mutating one will change it for every future call to that function. Because of that "gotcha," a common idiom is:

```
def find_path(..., path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
```

or (equivalently but less-common)

```
path = [] if path is None else path
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into what is passed as an argument for "path". I suspect your code somehow feeds it a tuple.

```
>>> (4,4) + []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    (4,4) + []
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
>>> [] + (4,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    [] + (4,4)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

The stacktrace you're getting corresponds to the 1st case, in which "path" is a tuple and [start] is, as expected, a list containing the tuple.

Comment: Well there's also the fact that he's defined a list literal, so we *know* the second element is a list by definition. There's no time when `[something]` isn't a list.